# Fusion Tables API: sometimes LineString is not displayed

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Google Fusion Tables API in my web application.
In my application, I'm using following api to draw kml(LineString).

```
var ftDefaultStyles = [{
  polylineOptions: {
  strokeColor: "#0000ff",
  strokeWeight: 6}
}];

ftLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map, //  google.maps.Map object
  styles: ftDefaultStyles,
  suppressInfoWindows: true
});

ftLayer.setOptions({
  styles: ftDefaultStyles,
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: tableId
  }
});
```

Several months ago(sorry, but not so clear), LineString had been displayed normally.
Now, sometimes LineString is not displayed.

When I investigated by Chrome DevTools(Network Tab),

**Displayed case**

http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/ja_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/%7Binfowindow,stats,controls%7D.js

was called.

**Not displayed case**

http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/ja_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/%7Bstats,controls%7D.js

was called.

If I clear my cache, "%7Binfowindow,stats,controls%7D.js" is called, and LineString is displayed at first request.
However, "%7Bstats,controls%7D.js" is almost called from next request.

Is this a api bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you use the [released or the frozen version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)? If so, you should probably file an [issue (more useful if it includes enough code to replicate the issue or a jsfiddle that does)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)

Comment: I did not explicitly specify a version, so experimental version(3.14) was used.
To specify version 3.14 (Experimental) or 3.13(Release), the same problem occurs.
To specify version 3.12 (Frozen), LineString has been displayed and "%7Binfowindow,stats,controls%7D.js" is called each time.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If that is the case, you should file an issue in the [issue tracker for the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), and probably bring it up in the Fusion Tables Users Group (not sure who needs to fix it, the maps people or the fusion tables people, but from your information in the question, looks like the maps API.

Comment: Associated [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5942)